# ``key-one=value one'' versus ``key-one={value one}'' in l3keys or package options

Tags: package-writing, l3keys

I just noticed that `key-one=value one` and `key-one={value one}` seem equivalent as `\keys_set:nn` arguments but not as package options.
In next minimal example, the same key-value argument is parsed as a package option or by `\keys_set:nn`. In the first case only some spaces are gobbled.
Is there any good reason for this to happen? Isn't it just a bug?

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{test.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage
  {test}
  {}
  {}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \MyOne
\tl_new:N \MyTwo
\keys_define:nn { test } {
  key-one .tl_set:N = \MyOne,
  key-two .tl_set:N = \MyTwo,
}
\cs_set:Npn \MyKeysSet #1 {
  \keys_set:nn { test } { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\ProcessKeysOptions{test}
%
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[
  key-one=value one,
  key-two={value two},
] {test}
\begin{document}
\noindent
key-one=\MyOne
\\key-two=\MyTwo
\MyKeysSet{
  key-one=value one,
  key-two={value two},
}
\\key-one=\MyOne
\\key-two=\MyTwo
\\Only the first ``valueone'' has no spaces: why?
\end{document}
```

[image: minimal example showing the difference]

Comment: The LaTeX kernel strips all non-protected spaces from package options: this is well-documented if 'interesting' behaviour.

Comment: For any new development don't use `l3keys2e`. Use `\ProcessKeyOptions[<module>]` directly. Better behaviour, no weirdly stripped spaces, supports resolving the dreaded "options clash" error. Or use the far superior `expkv-opt` (well, not really far superior, just `expkv` based, but I wrote that...).

Comment: Unfortunately for various reasons, relying on `\ProcessKeyOptions` is not an option.

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS `\ifdefined\ProcessKeyOptions\ProcessKeyOptions[test]\else\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}\ProcessKeysOptions{test}\fi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally the options for classes and packages are subject to `\zap@space`, which will remove any space not "hidden" inside braces, and might accidentally strip braces, the result is stored in the `\opt@<name>.<ext>` list.

Nowadays there is a second list `\@raw@opt@<name>.<ext>` that wasn't zapped. `\ProcessKeyOptions` will parse that list instead.

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage
  {test}
  {}
  {}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \MyOne
\tl_new:N \MyTwo
\keys_define:nn { test } {
  key-one .tl_set:N = \MyOne,
  key-two .tl_set:N = \MyTwo,
}
\cs_set:Npn \MyKeysSet #1 {
  \keys_set:nn { test } { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ProcessKeyOptions[test]
%
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[
  key-one=value one,
  key-two={value two},
] {test}
\begin{document}
\noindent
key-one=\MyOne
\\key-two=\MyTwo
\MyKeysSet{
  key-one=value one,
  key-two={value two},
}
\\key-one=\MyOne
\\key-two=\MyTwo
\\Only the first ``valueone'' has no spaces: why?
\end{document}
```